# Doesn't seem to be a way to send full stack traces over syslogappender in log4j2 using TCP Or AppenderComponentBuilder

Tags: java, slf4j, log4j2, rsyslog

I've been trying to send log4j2 logging to a rsyslog server using a ConfigurationFactory , and a config file. Niether ways resulted in an output compareable to logging to a file.

In all cases I'm using `log.error("test", new Throwable().fillInStackTrace());`

I tried doing this two different ways:

1. Using AppenderComponentBuilder

   @Plugin(name = "CustomConfigurationFactory", category = ConfigurationFactory.CATEGORY)
   @Order(50)

   public class Log4jConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {

   static Configuration createConfiguration(final String name, ConfigurationBuilder builder) {

   ```
   builder.setConfigurationName(name);
   builder.setStatusLevel(Level.INFO);

   AppenderComponentBuilder fileAppenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("logFile", FileAppender.PLUGIN_NAME)
       .addAttribute("fileName", "Audit.log");
   fileAppenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n"));

   KeyValuePair exc = new KeyValuePair("exception", "%ex");
   AppenderComponentBuilder syslogAppenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("syslog","Syslog")
           .addAttribute("host", "example.com")
           .addAttribute("port", 512)
           .addAttribute("protocol", "TCP")
           .addAttribute( "immediateFlush", true )
           .addAttribute( "newLine", true )
           .addAttribute("reconnectionDelayMillis", 10000)

           .addAttribute( "facility", "LOCAL5" )
           .addAttribute("format", "RFC5424")
           .addAttribute("appName","audit")
           .addAttribute("includeMDC",true)
           .addAttribute("enterpriseNumber", 18060)
           .addAttribute("id", "Audit")
           .addAttribute("mdcId", "mdc")
           .addAttribute("messageId","log");
   syslogAppenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("RFC5424Layout")
           .addAttribute("exceptionPattern", "%rThrowable{full}"));
       //    .addAttribute("LoggerFields", exc)); .. LoggerFields doesn't exist as an attribute so enabling full stack traces is impossible with the bare builder. See second attempt.


   builder.add(syslogAppenderBuilder);
   builder.add(fileAppenderBuilder);

   builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.INFO).
       add(builder.newAppenderRef("logFile")));
       add(builder.newAppenderRef("syslog")));

   Configuration config = builder.build();
   return config;  
   }

   @Override
   public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource source) {
       return getConfiguration(loggerContext, source.toString(), null);
   }

   @Override
   public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final String name, final URI configLocation) {
       ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = newConfigurationBuilder();
       return createConfiguration(name, builder);
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
       return new String[] {"*"};
   }
   ```

   }

(The first way had no way of adding a `LoggerFields` property so it was doomed to fail.) It displays `"ERROR test"`

2. Using SyslogAppender.Builder

   ```
   KeyValuePair[] exc = new KeyValuePair[4];
       exc[0] = new KeyValuePair("exception", "%ex");
       exc[1] = new KeyValuePair("thread", "%t");
       exc[2] = new KeyValuePair("priority", "%p");
       exc[3] = new KeyValuePair("category", "%c");
       LoggerFields[] lf = new LoggerFields[1];
       lf[0] = LoggerFields.createLoggerFields(exc, null, "18060", false);
       SyslogAppender.Builder syslogAppenderBuilder1 = SyslogAppender.newSyslogAppenderBuilder();
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.withName("syslog");
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.withHost("example.com");
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.withPort(512);
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.withProtocol(Protocol.TCP);
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.withImmediateFlush(true);
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setNewLine(true);
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setFacility(Facility.USER);
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setFormat("RFC5424");
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setAppName("Audit");
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setIncludeMdc(true);
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setEnterpriseNumber(18060);
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setId("audit");
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setMdcId("mdc");
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setMsgId("log");
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setExceptionPattern("%ex");
       syslogAppenderBuilder1.setLoggerFields(lf);

       builder.add(fileAppenderBuilder);
       builder.add(builder.newRootLogger(Level.INFO).
           add(builder.newAppenderRef("LogFile")));

       Configuration config = builder.build();
        config.getRootLogger().addAppender(syslogAppenderBuilder1.build(), Level.INFO, null);
       return config;
   ```

This results in displaying just an `"e"` or an `"n"`

3. Thirdly I gave up and decided to use a config file with UDP:

```html
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Syslog name="syslog" format="RFC5424" host="example.com" port="512" protocol="UDP" appName="Audit" newLine="true" immediateFlush="true" includeMDC="true" mdcId="mdc" facility="LOCAL5" enterpriseNumber="18060" messageId="log" id="audit" charset="UTF-8">
      <LoggerFields>
        <KeyValuePair key="thread" value="%t" />
        <KeyValuePair key="priority" value="%p" />
        <KeyValuePair key="category" value="%c" />
        <KeyValuePair key="exception" value="%rThrowable{full}" />
      </LoggerFields>
      <ExceptionPattern>%rThrowable{full}</ExceptionPattern>
    </Syslog>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="file" fileName="logs/Audit.log" filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
      </Policies>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="syslog" />
      <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This results in the following log output:
test#012java.lang.Throwable#012#011at main(main.java:5) [main.jar:?]#012

I assume #012 is new line and it's not being processed like it should be.

There doesnt seem to be a perfect way to send logs over to rsyslog. Any solutions?

Comment: I am facing same issue

Comment: I ended up using logback instead. Very simple setup and easy to make filers. Not sure about performance but it isn't important to me. Just make a zip folder and rename it to jar, put the logback.xml inside it, and include this jar when producing the jar of your program. This puts logback.xml directly on your classpath.